# How to make the FirstResponder "Done" button on the k/b blue on a iPad?

Tags: ios, xcode4

I have an iPhone app where the FirstResponder "Done" button is blue.  I'm porting that app to the iPad, and the FirstResponder "Done" button stays grey.

I'm using XCode4 with Storyboards...

Is there anyway to change that so the Done button is blue?

Comment: are you using xibs, storyboards, or adding the button programmatically?

Comment: XCode4 with storyboards, not adding button programmatically - it's part of the keyboard.

Comment: You will want to ensure you are using a UIBarButtonItem.  If you add it to a Navigation Controller, it is blue by default.

Comment: Let me clarify this question:  it is the keyboard "done" button, which changes to blue when it becomes the FirstResponder on an iPhone app.  This is not happening on the iPad app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the "theme" for iPad is silver and gray; therefore it can't be easily done.  :-{

Answer (score 1):

Is this a `UIBarButtonItem`?  In iOS5 you can set the `tintColor` on a `UIBarButtonItem`.

Comment: No, it's the Done button on the keyboard

Comment: @spokane-dude does the grey "done" button actually say "done" or does it say "return"?

Comment: MDT:  says "Done"... a friend of mine tried a minimal iPad app test, and his was grey also... so I guess it can't be done.. :-{